# Pull data and display as rows and columns

Tags: sql, table

I am a noob when it comes to pulling data from tables and fields of a WP database so I'll explain it as best as I can without it running into a thesis.

I have a table called `WP_answer`.

In that table are multiple fields, but the 2 I want info from are "QST_ID" and "ANS_Value"

QST_ID contains 5 ID numbers, 11,12,13,14 & 15

They Correlate as follows:

- 11 would equal question: Year
- 12 would equal question: Make
- 13 would equal question: Model
- 14 would equal question: Engine
- 15 would equal question: Class

The ANS_Value already lines up with the QST_ID as submitted on the form. BUT because there will be close to 900 forms submitted that contains the 5 questions, that's a boat load of data.

How can I pull this data, put it into 5 columns on a current WP Page, and have each column header have the correct data name and for it to paginate after say 75 entries? I think I am making this more complicated that it is but after working 70 hours a week, my brain hurts anyways.

I appreciate any feedback and help that you guys give :)